# How to use cosine similarity as a distance metric with pyclustering's xmeans clustering module?

Tags: python-3.x

I would like to use cosine similarity as a distance metric in pyclustering's XMeans. Could you suggest how I may do that?

Comment: `sklearn` doesn't have a "XMeans" clustering method.

Comment: Thanks, I see. I find xmeans is implemented in pyclustering, can you suggest how I may use the cosine similarity metric there?

Comment: Looking at the source code, it appears that the underlying `kmeans` class does accept a user defined distance metric, but I don't see a way to pass that kwarg through `xmeans`.  Perhaps if you contacted the author for assistance, or rewrite/override `xmeans` distance measuring function, it is possible.